# When is spying on method useful during unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

With Jasmine it is possible to `spyOn` methods, but I'm not clear on when would it be actually useful. My understanding is that unit tests should not be concerned with implementation details and testing if method is called would be implementation detail.

One place I might think of is spying on `scope.$broadcast` (Angular) etc but then again this would be implementation detail and not sure if unit tests should even bother with how the code works, as long as it gives expected result.

Obviously there are good reasons to use `spyOn` so what would be good place to use it?

Comment: "tests should not be concerned with implementation details and testing if method is called would be implementation detail" --- it depends. When you implement a caching layer you need to ensure that underlying repository was invoked only once with contents being served from a cache afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The spyOn you describe is more commonly known in testing as a MOCK, although to be more clear it allows for 2 operations:

1. Create a new implementation for a method via `createSpy` (this is the classical mock)
2. Instrument an existing method via `spyOn` (this allows you to see if the method was called and with what args, the return value etc.)

Mocking in probably the most used technique in unit testing. When you are testing a unit of code, you'll often find that there are dependencies to other units of code, and those dependencies have their own dependencies etc. If you try to test everything you'll end up with an module / UI test, which are expensive and difficult to maintain (they are still valuable, but you want as few of those as possible)

This is where mocking comes in. Imagine your unit calls to a REST service for some data. You don't want to take a dependency on a service in your unit test. So you mock the method that calls the service and you provide your own implementation that simply returns some data. Want to check that your unit handles REST errors? Have your mock return an error. etc.

It can sometimes be useful to know if your code actually calls another unit of code - imagine that you want to make sure your code correctly calls a logging module. Just mock (spyOn) that logging module and assert that it was called X number of times with the proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can spy functions and then you will be able to assert a couple of things 
about it. You can check if it was called, what parameters it had, if it
returned something or even how many times it was called!
Spies are highly useful when writing tests, so I am going to explain how to
use the most common of them here.

```
        // This is our SUT (Subject under test)
        function Post(rest) {
          this.rest = rest; 
         rest.init();
        }
```

We have here our SUT which is a Post constructor. It uses a RestService to
 fetch its stuff. Our Post will delegate all the Rest work to the RestService
which will be initialized when we create a new Post object. Let’s start testing
 it step by step:

```
    `describe('Posts', function() {
      var rest, post;
      beforeEach(function() {
        rest = new RestService();
        post = new Post(rest);
      });
    });`
```

Nothing new here. Since we are going to need both instances in every test,
we put the initialization on a `beforeEach` so we will have a new instance every
time.
 Upon Post creation, we initialize the `RestService`. We want to test that, how
 can we do that?:

```
    `it('will initialize the rest service upon creation', function() {
      spyOn(rest, 'init');
      post = new Post(rest);
      expect(rest.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });`
```

We want to make sure that init on rest is being called when we create a new
Post object. For that we use the jasmine spyOn function. The first parameter is
the object we want to put the spy and the second parameter is a string which
represent the function to spy. In this case we want to spy the function `init`
on the spy object. Then we just need to create a new Post object that will call
that init function. The final part is to assert that rest.init have been
called. Easy right? Something important here is that the when you spy a 
function, the real function is never called. So here rest.init doesn’t actually
run.